# Sharing files in different projects to the same folder in HG/Git

Tags: git, file, mercurial, sharing

We are trying to move from Visual SourceSafe(VSS)/SourceOffsite(SOS) to HG/Git, there is one major problem that we have no idea how to deal with it properly.

We distribute C++ source files to our users as part of our "Product X", these source files are of course version controlled.
Let's say the source files are organized like this:

> {Product X install folder}\SDK\system*.h
>   {Product X install folder}\SDK\Src*.cpp

So far so good.
For some advanced users, additional files are provided to make our "Product X Professional version", and these files are also put under the same location as mentioned above.

This won't be a problem with VSS because VSS support [sharing of files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y90e01b4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Here's how we managed source files in VSS:

We have a project in VSS for the "basic/non-pro" version

> $/Support/**CoreVersion**/SDK/system/*.h
>
>   $/Support/**CoreVersion**/SDK/Src/*.cpp

And we have a project for "pro" version, it only contains files for advanced users

> $/Support/**Pro**/SDK/system/*.h
>
>   $/Support/**Pro**/SDK/Src/*.cpp

Finally, the files for two different versions can be shared to the same project:

> $/**SourceBase**/SDK/system/
>   $/**SourceBase**/SDK/Src/

Then developers just need to work on $/SourceBase/.

Now, we can't figure out how can this be done in HG/Git, because there is no "file sharing" any more.

We are aware of "sub repository", however it seems to be designed for subpath only, this is not our case because those files have to be put under the same folder, and we don't want to change the file structure unless it's the last resort.

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use 2 branches to do this. One is pro, one is std, all development goes to the pro branch and the std branch only accepts merges.

Initially you can put all files in the pro branch, and make the initial commit. Then delete the non-std files, commit and create the std branch.

Now everyone switch to pro branch and do the development, when need std build, just merge from pro and choose Remove when solving the Changed-Removed conflicts.